# SqlAlchemy Python. From mysql to sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can i translate next mysql code to sqlAlchemy:

```
       SELECT
                u.id AS writer_id,
                u.user_login AS user_login,
                m.message_id AS message_id,
                m.message,
                m.time
            FROM
                (SELECT
                    message_id, tm.writer_id, tm.receiver_id, message, time
                FROM
                    test_messages tm
                WHERE
                    (tm.writer_id = 1 AND tm.receiver_id = 2)
                        OR (tm.writer_id = 2 AND tm.receiver_id = 1)
                ORDER BY tm.time DESC
                LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) AS m
                    LEFT JOIN
                users u ON u.id = m.writer_id
            ORDER BY (m.time);
```

I tried next:

```
s = select([
    users.c.id,
    users.c.user_login,
    messages.c.message_id,
    messages.c.message,
    messages.c.time
]).select_from(
    select([
        messages.c.message_id,
        messages.c.writer_id,
        messages.c.receiver_id,
        messages.c.message,
        messages.c.time
    ]).where(
        or_(
            and_(
                messages.c.writer_id == writer_id,
                messages.c.receiver_id == receiver_id
            ),
            and_(
                messages.c.writer_id == receiver_id,
                messages.c.receiver_id == writer_id
            )
        )
    ).select_from(
        users.outerjoin(messages, users.c.id == messages.c.writer_id)
    ).order_by(messages.c.time.desc())
).order_by(messages.c.time)

response = await conn.execute(s)

headers = response.keys()
rows = await response.fetchall()
```

Having problems with aliases.
`pymysql.err.InternalError: (1248, 'Every derived table must have its own alias')`
I've written the whole subquery, but there is a problem with alias. Should i set explicitly alias or what should i do?
Help please.

Comment: You'd not normally instantiate a `Query` like that, but through a session's `query` property, or you'd use Core constructs such as `select()`. I'd recommend that you read the tutorials: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html and http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html. On your query construct, it'd seem you've misplased the join. Your original SQL selects from the subquery, joined with user. Your current SQLA construct would join in the to-be-subquery.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Yes, but i don't know how to write query with subquery. And with join.

Comment: That's why you should read the tutorials. Specifically the part handling [subqueries](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries).

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Ok. Thank's.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä I've changed code and post. Could you look at this  please. Now i have problem with aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using [Core and the SQL Expression Language](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html) you could form an equivalent query with:

```
In [25]: subq = messages.select().\
    ...:     where(or_(
    ...:         and_(
    ...:             messages.c.writer_id == writer_id,
    ...:             messages.c.receiver_id == receiver_id
    ...:         ),
    ...:         and_(
    ...:             messages.c.writer_id == receiver_id,
    ...:             messages.c.receiver_id == writer_id
    ...:         )
    ...:     )).\
    ...:     order_by(messages.c.time.desc()).\
    ...:     limit(10).\
    ...:     alias()

In [26]: s = select([users.c.id,
    ...:             users.c.user_login,
    ...:             subq.c.message_id,
    ...:             subq.c.message,
    ...:             subq.c.time]).\
    ...:     select_from(
    ...:         subq.
    ...:         outerjoin(users, users.c.id == subq.c.writer_id)).\
    ...:     order_by(subq.c.time)
```

Note the use of [`alias()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-aliases). Your original SQL had the join the other way around compared to your query construct attempt, so I've followed the original SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much. I see that i did wrong. I tried do alias after subq. subq_al = subq.alias(). Thank's you.

Comment: Most of SQLA constructs and methods are "generative" in that they produce new objects instead of altering the existing one.

Comment: Does it mean that in this line: `subq_al = subq.alias() ` i've created a new one object that doen't connect to subq?

Comment: Exactly. The original object's state is not modified. The new object is a copy of the original with the aliasing applied.